# debugging WC_Shipping_Method packages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created an extended class out of WC_Shipping_Method and needed to debug and printout $packages in calculate_shipping method.

1. var_dump is not showing anything on screen. Is there anyway to display the content of such variable?
2. Another issue I noticed that $this->title is not changed, I run it first time and the shipment name is somehow become fixed!

   ```
   function tutsplus_shipping_method() {
       if ( ! class_exists( 'TutsPlus_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
           class TutsPlus_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
               /**
                * Constructor for your shipping class
                *
                * @access public
                * @return void
                */
               public function __construct() {
                   $this->id                 = 'tutsplus'; 
                   $this->method_title       = __( 'TutsPlus Shipping', 'tutsplus' );  
                   $this->method_description = __( 'Custom Shipping Method for TutsPlus', 'tutsplus' ); 

                   // Availability & Countries
                   $this->availability = 'including';
                   $this->countries = array(
                       'US', // Unites States of America
                       'CA', // Canada
                       'DE', // Germany
                       'GB', // United Kingdom
                       'IT',   // Italy
                       'ES', // Spain
                       'HR'  // Croatia
                       );

                   $this->init();

                   $this->enabled = isset( $this->settings['enabled'] ) ? $this->settings['enabled'] : 'yes';
                   $this->title = isset( $this->settings['title'] ) ? $this->settings['title'] : __( 'TutsPlus Shipping', 'tutsplus' );
               }

               /**
                * Init your settings
                *
                * @access public
                * @return void
                */
               function init() {
                   // Load the settings API
                   $this->init_form_fields(); 
                   $this->init_settings(); 

                   // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                   add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
               }

               /**
                * Define settings field for this shipping
                * @return void 
                */
               function init_form_fields() { 

                   $this->form_fields = array(

                    'enabled' => array(
                         'title' => __( 'Enable', 'tutsplus' ),
                         'type' => 'checkbox',
                         'description' => __( 'Enable this shipping.', 'tutsplus' ),
                         'default' => 'yes'
                         ),

                    'title' => array(
                       'title' => __( 'Title', 'tutsplus' ),
                         'type' => 'text',
                         'description' => __( 'Title to be display on site', 'tutsplus' ),
                         'default' => __( 'TutsPlus Shipping', 'tutsplus' )
                         ),

                    'weight' => array(
                       'title' => __( 'Weight (kg)', 'tutsplus' ),
                         'type' => 'number',
                         'description' => __( 'Maximum allowed weight', 'tutsplus' ),
                         'default' => 100
                         ),

                    );

               }

               /**
                * This function is used to calculate the shipping cost. Within this function we can check for weights, dimensions and other parameters.
                *
                * @access public
                * @param mixed $package
                * @return void
                */
               public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {

                   $weight = 0;
                   $cost = 0;
                   $country = $package["destination"]["country"];

                   foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) 
                   { 
                       $_product = $values['data']; 
                       $weight = $weight + $_product->get_weight() * $values['quantity']; 
                   }

                   $weight = wc_get_weight( $weight, 'kg' );

                   if( $weight <= 10 ) {

                       $cost = 0;

                   } elseif( $weight <= 30 ) {

                       $cost = 5;

                   } elseif( $weight <= 50 ) {

                       $cost = 10;

                   } else {

                       $cost = 20;

                   }

                   $countryZones = array(
                       'HR' => 0,
                       'US' => 3,
                       'GB' => 2,
                       'CA' => 3,
                       'ES' => 2,
                       'DE' => 1,
                       'IT' => 1
                       );

                   $zonePrices = array(
                       0 => 10,
                       1 => 30,
                       2 => 50,
                       3 => 70
                       );

                   $zoneFromCountry = $countryZones[ $country ];
                   $priceFromZone = $zonePrices[ $zoneFromCountry ];

                   $cost += $priceFromZone;

                   $rate = array(
                       'id' => $this->id,
                       'label' => $this->title,
                       'cost' => $cost
                   );

                   $this->add_rate( $rate );

               }
           }
       }
   }

   add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'tutsplus_shipping_method' );

   function add_tutsplus_shipping_method( $methods ) {
       $methods[] = 'TutsPlus_Shipping_Method';
       return $methods;
   }

   add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_tutsplus_shipping_method' );

   function tutsplus_validate_order( $posted )   {

       $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();

       $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

       if( is_array( $chosen_methods ) && in_array( 'tutsplus', $chosen_methods ) ) {

           foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {

               if ( $chosen_methods[ $i ] != "tutsplus" ) {

                   continue;

               }

               $TutsPlus_Shipping_Method = new TutsPlus_Shipping_Method();
               $weightLimit = (int) $TutsPlus_Shipping_Method->settings['weight'];
               $weight = 0;

               foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) 
               { 
                   $_product = $values['data']; 
                   $weight = $weight + $_product->get_weight() * $values['quantity']; 
               }

               $weight = wc_get_weight( $weight, 'kg' );

               if( $weight > $weightLimit ) {

                       $message = sprintf( __( 'Sorry, %d kg exceeds the maximum weight of %d kg for %s', 'tutsplus' ), $weight, $weightLimit, $TutsPlus_Shipping_Method->title );

                       $messageType = "error";

                       if( ! wc_has_notice( $message, $messageType ) ) {

                           wc_add_notice( $message, $messageType );

                       }
               }
           }       
       } 
   }

   add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents', 'tutsplus_validate_order' , 10 );
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'tutsplus_validate_order' , 10 );
   ```

Comment: Use the inbuilt WordPress debugging commands ie error_log() to write to the debug.log file.  You'll need to enable debugging in wp-config.php.

Comment: that worked successfully, but I am still having the title problem.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I created the log file and was able to check its content